# How to change default port EMM WSO

Tags: wso2-iot

How to change default port  EMM WSO2, Change management port 9443
I have ESB e EMM installed in only one server but the two services used port 9443.
I need change EMM port number.

Comment: This might be a better question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: change the port offset of EMM in carbon.xml file. it will change all port numbers with the given offset.  check this out: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Configuring+WSO2+EMM+with+Port+Offset

Answer (score 4):

The default HTTP and HTTPS ports of a WSO2 product are 9763 and 9443 respectively. You can change the port by increasing the port offset, default offset is 0, you increase value to the offset this will result in a new port for the wso2 emm server.New port value will be the default value plus the offset value.

**Ex:

For port offset 1 HTTPS port will be 9443. 

For port offset 1 HTTP port will be 9763.

For port offset 2 HTTPS port will be 9444.**

There are two ways to set an offset to a port:

- Pass the port offset to the server during startup. The following
  command starts the server with the default port incremented by
  3:./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=3
- Set the Ports section of
  /repository/conf/carbon.xml as
  follows:3